# AWS Elemental MediaConvert - Remote Input Different from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, video-streaming, transcoding, aws-media-convert

I've already developed a service that takes a pool of MP4 files and transforms them into HLS format for VoD-related purposes.

I'm considering migrating my solution towards AWS Elemental MediaConvert, which seems very promising. The only problem is, the videos I want to process do not exist on an S3 bucket or anything related to AWS for that matter. They sit on a remote server.

TLDR; The question is, can I use AWS Elemental MediaConvert and feed into it MP4 Files that **do not exist on an S3 bucket**? I have read the documentation and I couldn't find anything that would help me implement such a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I hadn't been looking hard enough in the documentation, which [clearly tells](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/upload-input-files.html#http-input-requirements) me I can.